# Why are NULLs sorted first?

Tags: sql-server, database-theory, sorting

Why is it that when we have a NULL value in a column and we order by the value ascending, the NULLs are sorted first?

```
select 1 as test
union all
select 2
union all
select NULL
union all
select 3
union all
select 4
order by test
```

results in

```
NULL
1
2
3
4
```

I keep thinking that NULL meant "Indeterminant" or possible "Unknown".  If that's true, wouldn't they sort last, since the value could be greater than all other values?  (Or is this a sorting option somewhere?)

I'm on SQL Server 2008R2, but I suspect this is true across all SQL Servers, and probably across all RDBMSs.

Comment: Oracle lists it last. That screwed me up once, believing it should behave like SQL Server.

Comment: "If that's true, wouldn't they sort last, since the value could be greater than all other values". The value could be less than all other values too. To me, it's intuitive that a falsey value like null should be on the lower end. And practical, since in practice, you often want to use `desc` ordering to show the biggest or most recent things, in which case I'd be glad for null things to be last.

Comment: The database does what you tell it to do. If you know that your data contains nulls and you have some business reason for sorting the data a certain way, then you need to specify that in either the query or the code/view that processes/displays the data. Never leave sorting up to the default database behavior.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> [BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191504.aspx): A value of NULL indicates that the value is unknown. A value of NULL
>   is different from an empty or zero value. No two null values are
>   equal. Comparisons between two null values, or between a NULL and any
>   other value, return unknown because the value of each NULL is unknown.

NULL means unknown. No other interpretation is valid.

> If that's true, wouldn't they sort last, since the value could be
>   greater than all other values?

There is no *could be*. There is no *potential* value. Unknown is unknown is unknown.

As to why it appears first, rather than last, this is not catered for by published SQL standards and is unfortunately left to the discretion of the RDBMS vendor:

> [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29#Grouping_and_sorting): The SQL standard does not explicitly define a default sort order for
>   Nulls. Instead, on conforming systems, Nulls can be sorted before or
>   after all data values by using the NULLS FIRST or NULLS LAST clauses
>   of the ORDER BY list, respectively. Not all DBMS vendors implement
>   this functionality, however. Vendors who do not implement this
>   functionality may specify different treatments for Null sorting in the
>   DBMS.

Comment: So, it's a judgment call.  That makes a lot of sense.  Thanks!

Comment: Good answer, thank you. Of course since "No two null values are equal", GROUP BY should not group NULLs together, which it does (at least in MS SQL)

Answer (score 6):

You are correct that `NULL` can mean 'Indeterminant' or 'Uknownn' or 'Not known yet' or 'Not applying'. But there is no reason to put the Nulls first or last. If we don't know the actual values, then tehy can be small or large.

I think the standard for determinign the wanted behaviour of Nulls during sorting, is:

```
ORDER BY 
    test NULLS LAST                      --- or NULLS FIRST for the opposite
```

Unfortunately SQL-Server hasn't adopted this syntax yet. If I'm not wrong PostgreSQL and Oracle have it.

One solution:

```
ORDER BY 
     CASE WHEN test IS NOT NULL 
            THEN 0 
          ELSE 1 
     END 
   , test
```

Another solution that needs adjustment depending the datatype - but will not preform well, as it can't use an index on `(test)`:

```
ORDER BY 
    COALESCE(test, 2147483647)               --- if it's a 4-byte signed integer
```

Comment: In this way ORDER BY 
    COALESCE(test, 2147483647) SQL server can not use Index.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know *why* it's done that way, but by definition NULLS can't be compared to non-NULLS, so they either have to go at the start or the end (Mark's answer covers this in a lot more detail).

To get the behaviour you want - As far as I know there's no sorting option to put nulls last, so you have to bodge it by using a computed column to force them last. However, in SQL Server you can't order by a computed column (`CASE WHEN ...`) when your data contains a set operator (`UNION ALL`). So:

```
CREATE TABLE #sorttest(test int)
INSERT INTO #sorttest values(1)
INSERT INTO #sorttest values(5)
INSERT INTO #sorttest values(4)
INSERT INTO #sorttest values(NULL)
INSERT INTO #sorttest values(3)
INSERT INTO #sorttest values(2)
SELECT test
FROM #sorttest
ORDER BY CASE WHEN test IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, test

DROP TABLE #sorttest
```

Will work for sorting nulls last. If you have to use `UNION` (or `EXCEPT` or `INTERSECTS`) to generate your data set, then dump your data to a temporary table as above.

Comment: ...or use the UNIONed output as a derived table.

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with numbers you can also use

```
ORDER BY -test DESC
```

`NULL` are the lowest possible values, therefore `DESC` puts them at the end.
Meanwhile the not null values have the sign inverted so `DESC` actually is an `ASC` on the real values.
This should be faster than `CASE` and I suppose that query optimizer can also use indexes on `test` column.

Comment: No, it wouldn't be able to use an index for the sort. Unless you have an index on the computed expression `(- test)`.

Comment: Clever, even though limited to numeric data only (appropriate for OP's example anyway). I'm not sure if this would indeed be faster than using CASE but I'm sure it wouldn't use an index (unless it's what @ypercubeᵀᴹ says – but then a CASE expression could be indexed in exactly the same way).